# Get all elements in the format "_ (10 RANDOM CHARACTERS) " from a webpage javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, jquery-selectors

I have a webpage that has a table with table rows inside like the format below

```
<tr id="_C15DKNWCSV">text</tr>
```

I'm trying to scan the webpage and get all the table rows that follow the format:

```
id="_(10 RANDOM CHARACTERS)"
```

and the place them in a array,

I know It's something to do with **querySelectorAll** But I can't get the random character filter to work.

## CODE and What I've done:

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
var current_queue_items = document.getElementById("v_viewable_items").querySelectorAll("[id^='_']")
```

while this works it not very robust, If something happens to start with "_" it'll be accepted, I'll also maybe add a IF Statement that only accepts it if its 11 characters long.

Comment: have you tried anything so far ? any code ?

Comment: Take a look at [*attribute selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: You'll probably need to use `Array filter` as well as the appropriate css selector

Comment: @Noob Please check update :)

Comment: @RobG I've tried this, but can't seem to get wildcards to work like random characters.

Comment: @JaromandaX I will look into this :)

Comment: Can whatever service is generating, or importing, the html add a predictable suffix, or a more specific prefix than just the underscore? Something that allows for: `.querySelectorAll("[id^='_predictablePrefix'][id$=‘predictableSuffix’]")`?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm unsure with the "Jargon" you've used, Can you explain via example, I'm new to programming and my English isn't great.

Comment: The prefix is the string before the random sequence of characters, in your code prefix is the underscore. The suffix is the same, but it’s at the end of the string. The code, above, would select: `<tagName id=“_predictablePrefix_C15DKNWCSV_predictableSuffix”>…</tagName>` and any other elements with an `id` with a different string of zero or more characters between the ‘predictable’ parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian's answer is OK, but it lacks explanation of what's going on.

Attribute selectors provide some options for matching attribute values, but they aren't as comprehensive as say regular expressions. In this case, likely the best you can do is limit the initial selection as much as you can, then filter out what you want after that.

So you can use:

- the TR selector to get only TR elements
- attribute selector of ID
- "^" starts with selector to get those with ID starting with underscore

Then you can filter out the ones you don't want using a regular expression, e.g.

```
var current_queue_items = [...document.getElementById("v_viewable_items")
  .querySelectorAll("TR[id^='_']")]
  .filter(node => /^_.{10}$/.test(node.id));
```

Which will return an array of TR elements within the "v_viewable_items" table or tbody or whatever it is that have an ID that fit the regular expression `/^_.{10}$/`.

You could also do:

```
document.getElementById("v_viewable_items")
  .querySelectorAll("TR[id^='_']")
  .forEach(node => {
    if (/^_.{10}$/.test(node.id)) {
      // do stuff with node
    }
  });
```

PS I don't like "dot chaining" like this but it's concise and OK for an example.

Note that if "v_viewable_items" is a table or tbody, then you could also do:

```
let current_queue_items = [...document.getElementById("v_viewable_items").rows]
  .filter(row => /^_.{10}$/.test(row.id));
```

Or instead of *filter* use *forEach* as above.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark this as the answer as it explains the solutions and how to do the task clearly and precisely with as much information as needed.

Comment: @RobG the .map(node => /^_.{10}$/.test(node.id)); just returned an array of true and false. Chage map for filter

Answer (score 0):

Using only querySelectorAll it isn't posible, so a posible solution can be obtain all elements that start with "_" using querySelectorAll and then filter with a regular expression.

Here I do an example where append a text to all TR selected

The script:

```
var customSelect = function() {
    var startWith_= [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[id^=_]')];
    var selected = startWith_.filter(e => /\_.{10}$/.test(e.id));
    // Do what you want here. . .
    selected.forEach( e => e.append('TR selected'));
}
```

Html test:

```
  <button onclick='customSelect()' >Custom Select</button>
  <br />
  <table>
    <tr id="_ABCEF56789">
        <td>It's ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="_0123456789">
        <td>It's ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="_01234567890">
        <td>It has more</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="_ABCEFghijk">
        <td>It's ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="_012345678">
        <td>It has less</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="A0123456789">
        <td>It start with no _</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: please [edit] your answer to include a description of how your answer solves the problem so that the OP and future visitors might learn something useful to apply to their own code. Specifically the filter function, the regular expression, and the use of the spread operator used to create an Array from the NodeList.

Comment: If you're going to use a function expression you might as well go the whole hog: `let addTRs = () => [...].filter(...).forEach(...);`. ;-) But I think function declarations are clearer and easier to maintain. It could just be done as `querySelectorAll(...).forEach(...)` and filter out the unwanted elements within the *forEach*.

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree, While I appreciate the answer I don't really understand what's happening.

Comment: personally, to answer the question accurately, I'd use `'tr[id^=_]'`

Comment: @b0nfire - `startWith_` will be what (almost) you've done. `selected` will be an array of elements where the id's match your requirement. `selected.forEach` simply adds a text node at the end of TR, which makes zero sense, but that's I guess showing where you do what you need to do with the array of elements you want

Comment: @JaromandaX  good improve with 'tr[id^=_]'. Now I'll edit the answer with this.